# aspx page, make a figure appear on screen, but now shot up when printing

Tags: asp.net, printing, hide, figure

I am designing a menu. I want it to appear when one visits the page online, but I do not want it to print.

Is there some setting in the properties(one gets to this when right clicking on a figure in design page of the .aspx file)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

There's no specific property in the aspx or in the controls. However, you can use css to modify the visibility or layout of the printed form.

Here's more info http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/11/24/how-to-set-up-a-print-style-sheet/

Comment: Thanks Rich, so to be clear , there is no way to modify the source code of the .aspx file to get the menu to not show up when printing?

Comment: Correct. You have to do it via css. I guess you could explicitly create an aspx that you intend to use as the "Print" view and exclude it there. But has it's own set of usability issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS!

```
@media print
{
     .hideonprint{display:none;}   
}
@media screen
{
    .hideonprint{display:table-cell;}    
}
```

and set the class of menuwrapper to hideonprint